# How to HTML-encode in the JSP expression language?

Tags: java, jsp, el, html-encode

Consider the following piece of JSP:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="${flashVars}" />
```

The value of `${flashVars}` contains ampersands and needs to be encoded before it is output. Instead, JSP expects the value of `${flashVars}` to be a piece of HTML and outputs the ampersands verbatim, resulting in bad HTML.

I found out that I can get the value to be encoded if I write it like this:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="<c:out value="${flashVars}"/>" />
```

But this looks really ugly and confuses my IDE to boot. Is there a better way to get the same result?

Comment: If IDE is the only problem with the above, then get another IDE - Intellij IDEA is great.

Comment: My main problem is it looks ugly. :-) I don't want to nest a tag in an attribute of another tag.

Comment: I don't blame Eclipse; it's a very complicated, non-compositional templating language which makes it very difficult to do proper highlighting/error reporting without writing a full compiler for it (which is not Eclipse's job here IMHO).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<param name="FlashVars" value="${fn:escapeXml(flashVars)}" />
```