# Fetch html markup from database and show in a div

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm having a table in MySql which has html markup in it. I'm trying to load that data in in a div but instead of showing html its showing me the html markup as it is.

instead of showing
'**Sushil**'

it is shows `<div><h3>Sushil</h3></div>`.

I'm using JSP as server side component. It fetches data from database using JSTL  tag.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: You will need to provide much more information about how exactly you are showing the data currently if you want a useful answer.

Comment: when you look at the source of the page, what does it show? Is your text from the db entity encoded?

Comment: Your HTML is escaped. What language are you using server-side?

Comment: @dnagirl source code shows me '<div><h3>Sushil</h3></div>'

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie i'm using JSP on server side

Comment: Show the code where you print this content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old class I've made years ago that could be useful, use like this :

```
out.println(HTML.decode(contentFromDB));



package com.spectotechnologies.util;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandre Lavoie
 */
public class HTML
{
    private static final int HTML_ENTITIES_MINUS_CHARACTER = 160;

    private static final int HTML_ENTITIES_START_CHARACTER = 32;

    private static final String HTML_ENCODING_TABLE[] = {
        "&nbsp;",   //
        "&#33;",    // !
        "&quot;",   // "
        "&#35;",    // #
        "&#36;",    // $
        "&#37;",    // %
        "&amp;",    // &
        "&#39;",    // '
        "&#40;",    // (
        "&#41;",    // )
        "&#42;",    // *
        "&#43;",    // +
        "&#44;",    // ,
        "&#45;",    // -
        "&#46;",    // .
        "&frasl;",  // /
        "&#48;",    // 0
        "&#49;",    // 1
        "&#50;",    // 2
        "&#51;",    // 3
        "&#52;",    // 4
        "&#53;",    // 5
        "&#54;",    // 6
        "&#55;",    // 7
        "&#56;",    // 8
        "&#57;",    // 9
        "&#58;",    // :
        "&#59;",    // ;
        "&lt;",     // <
        "&#61;",    // =
        "&gt;",     // >
        "&#63;",    // ?
        "&#64;",    // @
        "&#65;",    // A
        "&#66;",    // B
        "&#67;",    // C
        "&#68;",    // D
        "&#69;",    // E
        "&#70;",    // F
        "&#71;",    // G
        "&#72;",    // H
        "&#73;",    // I
        "&#74;",    // J
        "&#75;",    // K
        "&#76;",    // L
        "&#77;",    // M
        "&#78;",    // N
        "&#79;",    // O
        "&#80;",    // P
        "&#81;",    // Q
        "&#82;",    // R
        "&#83;",    // S
        "&#84;",    // T
        "&#85;",    // U
        "&#86;",    // V
        "&#87;",    // W
        "&#88;",    // X
        "&#89;",    // Y
        "&#90;",    // Z
        "&#91;",    // [
        "&#92;",    // /
        "&#93;",    // ]
        "&#94;",    // ^
        "&#95;",    // _
        "&#96;",    // `
        "&#97;",    // â
        "&#98;",    // b
        "&#99;",    // c
        "&#100;",   // d
        "&#101;",   // e
        "&#102;",   // f
        "&#103;",   // g
        "&#104;",   // h
        "&#105;",   // i
        "&#106;",   // j
        "&#107;",   // k
        "&#108;",   // l
        "&#109;",   // m
        "&#110;",   // n
        "&#111;",   // o
        "&#112;",   // p
        "&#113;",   // q
        "&#114;",   // r
        "&#115;",   // s
        "&#116;",   // t
        "&#117;",   // u
        "&#118;",   // v
        "&#119;",   // w
        "&#120;",   // x
        "&#121;",   // y
        "&#122;",   // z
        "&#123;",   // {
        "&#124;",   // |
        "&#125;",   // }
        "&#126;",   // ~
        "&#127;",   // 
        "&#128;",   // €
        "&#129;",   // �
        "&#130;",   // ‚
        "&#131;",   // ƒ
        "&#132;",   // „
        "&#133;",   // …
        "&#134;",   // †
        "&#135;",   // ‡
        "&#136;",   // ˆ
        "&permil;", // ‰
        "&#138;",   // Š
        "&lsaquo;", // ‹
        "&#140;",   // Œ
        "&#141;",   // �
        "&#142;",   // Ž
        "&#143;",   // �
        "&#144;",   // �
        "&#145;",   // ‘
        "&#146;",   // ’
        "&#147;",   // “
        "&#148;",   // ”
        "&#149;",   // •
        "&ndash;",  // –
        "&mdash;",  // —
        "&#152;",   // ˜
        "&trade;",  // ™
        "&#154;",   // š
        "&rsaquo;", // ›
        "&#156;",   // œ
        "&#157;",   // �
        "&#158;",   // ž
        "&#159;",   // Ÿ
        "&#160;",   //  
        "&iexcl;",  // ¡
        "&cent;",   // ¢
        "&pound;",  // £
        "&curren;", // ¤
        "&yen;",    // ¥
        "&brvbar;", // ¦
        "&sect;",   // §
        "&uml;",    // ¨
        "&copy;",   // ©
        "&ordf;",   // ª
        "&laquo;",  // «
        "&not;",    // ¬
        "&shy;",    // ­
        "&reg;",    // ®
        "&macr;",   // ¯
        "&deg;",    // °
        "&plusmn;", // ±
        "&sup2;",   // ²
        "&sup3;",   // ³
        "&acute;",  // ´
        "&micro;",  // µ
        "&para;",   // ¶
        "&middot;", // ·
        "&cedil;",  // ¸
        "&sup1;",   // ¹
        "&ordm;",   // º
        "&raquo;",  // »
        "&frac14;", // ¼
        "&frac12;", // ½
        "&frac34;", // ¾
        "&iquest;", // ¿
        "&Agrave;", // À
        "&Aacute;", // Á
        "&Acirc;",  // Â
        "&Atilde;", // Ã
        "&Auml;",   // Ä
        "&Aring;",  // Å
        "&AElig;",  // Æ
        "&Ccedil;", // Ç
        "&Egrave;", // È
        "&Eacute;", // É
        "&Ecirc;",  // Ê
        "&Euml;",   // Ë
        "&Igrave;", // Ì
        "&Iacute;", // Í
        "&Icirc;",  // Î
        "&Iuml;",   // Ï
        "&ETH;",    // Ð
        "&Ntilde;", // Ñ
        "&Ograve;", // Ò
        "&Oacute;", // Ó
        "&Ocirc;",  // Ô
        "&Otilde;", // Õ
        "&Ouml;",   // Ö
        "&times;",  // ×
        "&Oslash;", // Ø
        "&Ugrave;", // Ù
        "&Uacute;", // Ú
        "&Ucirc;",  // Û
        "&Uuml;",   // Ü
        "&Yacute;", // Ý
        "&THORN;",  // Þ
        "&szlig;",  // ß
        "&agrave;", // à
        "&aacute;", // á
        "&acirc;",  // â
        "&atilde;", // ã
        "&auml;",   // ä
        "&aring;",  // å
        "&aelig;",  // æ
        "&ccedil;", // ç
        "&egrave;", // è
        "&eacute;", // é
        "&ecirc;",  // ê
        "&euml;",   // ë
        "&igrave;", // ì
        "&iacute;", // í
        "&icirc;",  // î
        "&iuml;",   // ï
        "&eth;",    // ð
        "&ntilde;", // ñ
        "&ograve;", // ò
        "&oacute;", // ó
        "&ocirc;",  // ô
        "&otilde;", // õ
        "&ouml;",   // ö
        "&divide;", // ÷
        "&oslash;", // ø
        "&ugrave;", // ù
        "&uacute;", // ú
        "&ucirc;",  // û
        "&uuml;",   // ü
        "&yacute;", // ý
        "&thorn;",  // þ
        "&yuml;"    // ÿ
    };

    public static String encode(String p_sToEncode)
    {
        int nCountChars;
        String sResult = "";
        String sFound;

        // Check for characters to replace till end of string
        for(nCountChars = 0;nCountChars < p_sToEncode.length();nCountChars++)
        {
            // Init to current character
            sFound = "" + p_sToEncode.charAt(nCountChars);

            // Check if character is in the list
            if(p_sToEncode.charAt(nCountChars) >= HTML_ENTITIES_MINUS_CHARACTER)
            {
                sFound = HTML_ENCODING_TABLE[p_sToEncode.charAt(nCountChars) - HTML_ENTITIES_START_CHARACTER];
            }

            // Add to result
            sResult += sFound;
        }

        return sResult;
    }

    public static String decode(String p_sToDecode)
    {
        Pattern oPattern;
        Matcher oMatcher;
        String sCode;
        int nCode;

        oPattern = Pattern.compile("&\\#?[0-9,a-z,A-Z]*;");

        oMatcher = oPattern.matcher(p_sToDecode);

        StringBuffer oBuffer = new StringBuffer(p_sToDecode.length());

        while(oMatcher.find())
        {
            sCode = oMatcher.group(0);

            for(nCode = 0;nCode < HTML_ENCODING_TABLE.length;nCode++)
            {
                if(sCode.equals(HTML_ENCODING_TABLE[nCode]))
                {
                    sCode = "" + (char)(HTML_ENTITIES_START_CHARACTER + nCode);
                    break;
                }
            }

            oMatcher.appendReplacement(oBuffer,Matcher.quoteReplacement(sCode));
        }

        oMatcher.appendTail(oBuffer);

        return oBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you will have to escape your html entities.  so `<` becomes `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;`, and so on.</strike>

[How to HTML-encode in the JSP expression language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526502/how-to-html-encode-in-the-jsp-expression-language) might be a related question for you to work off of.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html is the spec for HTML entities in HTML 4 (I do not believe any more were created for HTML5, but I could be wrong)

EDIT: so, the reverse looks like there's a Java package from Apache Commons called "Commons Lang" that includes a `StringEscapeUtils` class that allows for escaping and unescaping HTML.

http://www.mytechtip.com/2009/02/encodedecode-html-in-java_6101.html

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: Actually he want exactly the inverse

Comment: @Kirean in database html is not escaped its as it is <h3>Sushil</h3>. It remains same even when JSP shows it but browser show the markup instead of showing headline

Comment: @SushilKumar My guess is that JSP is automatically escaping it when outputting, as that's the "normal" case of wanting to write out strings - you want the string, not what the string represents.  Not what you want here though.  ASP.NET (MVC) has a similar Html.Raw that provides for this, though I cant find an analogous jsp function for it

Comment: In JSF you have <h:outputText value="" escape="false" />, don't remember the equivalent in JSP... probably out.println(); will print straight HTML !