# How to prevent escape of html tags in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have some data inside my database with html tags like

```
<b>, <br>
```

But, when I try to store it into a model object and render it on a JSP, it is rendered with the tags. The tags are not evaluated.

Any idea on how to get my page to process those tags? Below is the code I use in my JSP.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <label>Comments</label>
    ${requestObject.comments}
</div>
```

Edit:
I tried the below code also, with no luck.

```
<c:out escapeXml="false" value="${requestObject.comments}" />
```

Database Content

```
<b>Oh Snap</b>
```

HTML Source

```
&lt;b&gt;Oh Snap&lt;&#x2f;b&gt;
```

I am expecting my text to be rendered bold

**Oh Snap**

Comment: what do you want ? To escape XML characters ? < --> &lt; ? or the other way, to actually output bold text ?

Comment: @Halley have you tried this? -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526502/how-to-html-encode-in-the-jsp-expression-language

Comment: Or use JSTL 'out' http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm which takes an ecsapeXML boolean attribute.

Comment: If you allow HTML in your database and that HTML can be user input, there are security concerns.

Comment: @ZNK-M to output bold text.

Comment: @Raedwald no, html wont be user input. thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is what you are seeking, but this should allow HTML to be evaluted:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="false" />
```

If you have Spring `form` or `message` tags, you can do: `htmlEscape="false"`.

UPDATE: 
Sadly, the `c:out` syntax will [take precedence](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/23600-problem-with-htmlescape) over the Spring tag on this but you can also try:

```
<spring:escapeBody htmlEscape="false">
   <%=requestObject.comments%>
</spring:escapeBody>
```

Comment: I donot want the html to escaped. I want the tags to be evaluated. I tried with `htmlEscape="false"`. Did not work.

Comment: Sorry, meant to write false on that.  Will revise my answer. I'm able to use that syntax with resource (.properties) files to evaluate HTML, so thinking that it would work from a DB.

Comment: it is not working for data from db via a model object.